# Как найти дубликаты в БД?

Tags: mysql

Делаю запрос к БД на поиск дубликатов. Соединил 3 таблицы и хочу удалить значения, которые совпадают по полям (t_s.l, t_s.t, t_s.w, t_m.a). Сделал выборку на поиск дубликатов:

```
SELECT
    count(t_s.l),
    count(t_s.t),
    count(t_s.w),
    count(t_m.a)
FROM
    tab_big as t_b
LEFT JOIN 
    tab_midl as t_m 
         on t_b.id = t_m.tb_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tab_small as t_s 
         on t_m.id = t_s.tm_id;
```

Вывод показал, что 6048 дубликатов.

Как мне посмотреть их и удалить после проверки?

Дополнение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнение 2 (Да, по таблицам видно будет, что таблица "tab_midl" отличается полем "b", но тем не менее, ее НАДО  считать Дублем, т.к. элементы в таблице "tab_small" одинаковы):

Таблица tab_big:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | bbb |
| 2 | bvb | sdd |

Таблица tab_midl:

| id | tb_id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 | 75 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 | 75 |

Таблица tab_small:

| id | tm_id | l | t | w | val_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | xc |
| 2 | 1 | 15 | 25 | 35 | sd |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 20 | 30 | xc |
| 4 | 2 | 15 | 25 | 35 | sd |
| 5 | 2 | 15 | 5 | 3 | d |
| 6 | 2 | 15 | 7 | 7 | s |

Дополнение №3 (Отделил в запросах на создание дубли от недублей)

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_big` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fl` float NOT NULL,
  `f2` float NOT NULL,
  `f3` float NOT NULL,
  `f4` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tab_big` (`id`,  `fl`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`) VALUES
(1, 0.0511719, 0.0878113, 0.894792, 0.430851),
(2, 0.0511719, 0.0878113, 0.894792, 0.430851),

(3, 0.06, 0.0878113, 0.894792, 0.430851),


CREATE TABLE `tab_midl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tb_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `f2` float NOT NULL,
  `f3` float NOT NULL,
  `f4` float NOT NULL,
  `f5` float NOT NULL,
  `a` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tab_midl` (`id`, `tb_id`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`, `a`) VALUES
(1, 1, 63, 0, 0, 1, 0.430851, 50),
(2, 1, 63, 0.176618, 0.262754, 0.308511, 1.1499, 50),
(3, 2, 63, 0, 0, 1, 0.430851, 50),
(4, 2, 63, 0.176618, 0.262754, 0.308511, 1.1499, 50),

(5, 3, 61, 0, 0, 2, 0.430851, 30),
(6, 3, 61, 0.176618, 0.262754, 0.308511, 1.1499, 70);



CREATE TABLE `tab_smal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l` float NOT NULL,
  `t` float NOT NULL,
  `w` float NOT NULL,
  `x` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `tab_smal` (`id`, `tm_id`, `l`, `t`, `w`, `x`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0.0973962, 0.705943, 0.0227891, 1),
(2, 1, 0.973962, 1.70594, 0.522, 0),
(3, 2, 0.0973962, 0.705943, 0.0227891, 1),
(4, 2, 0.973962, 1.70594, 0.522, 0)
(5, 3, 0.0973962, 0.705943, 0.0227891, 1),
(6, 3, 0.973962, 1.70594, 0.522, 0),
(7, 4, 0.0973962, 0.705943, 0.0227891, 1),
(8, 4, 0.973962, 1.70594, 0.522, 0)

(9, 5, 1.0973962, 3.705943, 5.0227891, 1),
(10, 6, 5.973962, 4.70594, 4.522, 0);
```

Дополнение 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откуда и что вы хотите удалить? и что называется дублями, если у вас 3 таблицы. значения которые есть во всех трех, или что?

Comment: @teran. внес дополнение

Comment: а почему вы рассматриваете все три таблицы целиком, а не в отдельности? Фактически на скрине дубль в третьей, видимо.

Comment: @teran, потому что значения в этих таблицах - как в матрешках, т.е. если в матрешке  лежит копия матрешки, то значит все ее дочери будут иметь такие же значения как и копия другой. Поэтому, по сути, надо удалить копию таблицы №2 ("tab_midl"), и соответственно все ссылки на Таблицу №2 из таблицы №3 ("tab_small")

Comment: Но! Записи в Таблице №2 не всегда одинаковы, например, там может быть 1 поле иметь другое значение. Но, то, что это копия - определяется именно таблицей №3, т.к. там все значения совпадают.

Comment: Убирайте свои весёлые картинки, а вместо них выкладывайте структуру, данные и требуемый результат. См. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169) и [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: *которые совпадают по полям (t_s.l, t_s.t, t_s.w, **t_s.a**)* - нет такого поля, оно в другой таблице.

Comment: *Сделал выборку на поиск дубликатов .. Вывод показал, что 6048 дубликатов* Эта выборка выводит что угодно, но только не количество дубликатов.

Comment: @Akina,  исправил **t_s.a** на **t_m.a**. Забыл исправить, но на картинке все верно нарисовано. Я же на картинке показал что как получается. Как по другому? Не могу же я взять  и БД Выгрузить на форум...

Comment: *Как по другому?* Прочитать предложенные ссылки ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО. *Не могу же я взять и БД Выгрузить на форму* Для создания адекватной модели вся БД не упёрлась. Достаточно 3-5-7 записей на таблицу.

Comment: @Akina, внес дополнение №2

Comment: *по таблицам видно будет, что таблица "tab_midl" отличается полем "b", но тем не менее, ее НАДО считать Дублем, т.к. элементы в таблице "tab_small" одинаковы* Из этого следует простой вывод - либо значения полей из "tab_midl" вообще не нужно выводить, либо нужно выводить одно определённое (ну, например, минимальное из имеющихся).

Comment: @Akina, дак я хочу очистить БД от этих дублей, и оставить записи только  минимальным значением поля "b" из таблицы "tab_midl". Но перед тем как удалить дубли я хочу проверить - правильно ли ищутся дубли, если так, то я их удалю. И, соответственно, в БД больше не будет дублей, а только записи в одном экземпляре с минимальным значением поля "b" (а если они одинаковы, то любое только 1 оставлю.)

Answer (score 0):

> я хочу очистить БД от этих дублей, и оставить записи только минимальным значением поля "b" из таблицы "tab_midl"

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM tab_midl t1
JOIN tab_midl t2 USING (tb_id, a)
WHERE t1.b > t2.b
-- OR (t1.b = t2.b AND t1.id > t2.id)
;
```

> перед тем как удалить дубли я хочу проверить - правильно ли ищутся дубли, если так, то я их удалю

Замени `DELETE t1` на `SELECT *`.

Comment: А он разве даст удаление? Ведь на удаляемые значения будет ссылаться таблица №3("tab_small")?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Конечно, надо сначала переустановить ссылки на оставляемую запись. По-моему, это очевидно. Кстати, "проверяющий" запрос как раз даст необходимые для этого данные.

Comment: Дак этот запрос покажет схожие записи, где значения по полю "b" больше. Он не не покажет дубли. Есть дубли или нет - определяются Таблицей №3

Comment: @АлексейБелкин В запрос на выборку попадут только те записи, которые имеют дубликаты. А если нет дубликата, то с третьей таблицей и делать ничего не требуется. *Есть дубли или нет - определяются Таблицей №3* Ну тогда добавьте две копии третьей таблицы в запросы-то.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Кстати, Вы так и не прочитали внимательно ссылки. Особенно первую, пункты 2.3 и 5.

Comment: дополнил таблицы, чтобы было понятно про что я говорю: Вот, например в Таблице №2 - 3 запись не является дублем, т.к. значения в Таблице №3 - разные

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Ну вот нахрена мне эти таблицы??? мне надо CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, чтобы я мог скопировать их и воссоздать у себя структуру с данными, и табличный результат для этих данных, чтобы сверить его с результатом запроса.

Comment: добавил запросы на создание

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Отлично. Хотя могли бы проверить на корректность - опечаток не одна и не две... вот то же, но в виде [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xw2YXVln). Теперь ещё хотелось бы увидеть требуемый результат после удаления "дубликатов" (состояние данных во второй таблице, в виде форматированной таблицы) - как я понял, записи, создающие дубли, должны удаляться только из неё.

Comment: Дополнил, что надо удалить. Там может показаться, что удаление идет от Таблицы №1, но на самом деле еще раз повторюсь, что дубли смотрятся по Таблице №3 (т.к. Таблица №1 может иметь одинаковые значения, но разные в таблице №3)